How to list all the resources that a group has been granted access to in Google Cloud?
I want a simple way to list out all the resources that a group has been granted access to in Google Cloud. One way is to iterate over all the projects and then check access granted to the group. This is the process I currently follow but it takes a while because of the numbers of projects we have.
Is there an easier way ?

According to this link, you can search all IAM policieswithin the specified accessible scope, such as a project, folder or organization.
For Google groups, such as group:devs@googlegroups.com:
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --query=policy:"group:devs@googlegroups.com" --scope=organizations/{YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NUMBER}


Accepted answer. Looks like I dont have access but the syntax is slightly off, it needs to be  --query=policy:dev@googlegroups.com

group: and user: before the email address is optional.
